# Do I need different ethereum adresses for every airdrop?

Tags: metamask, myetherwallet, airdrop

I want to register in some airdrops.
I need to type same ethereum address in all airdrops or I need to create new account in metamask so I have different ethereum address for every airdrop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by airdrop you mean receiving some (possibly ERC20) tokens, then generally no, you do not need a separate Ethereum address. As a matter of fact some "free" airdrops have been sent to existing Ethereum addresses with nonzero balance (either of Ether or existing ERC20 tokens) to spread the tokens without the need for address owners to do anything.

Anyway, you still need a small amount of Ether (gas) at the particular address to transfer the ERC20 tokens (cents to dollars, depending on how fast and certain you want the transfer to be). You do not have to add it immediately, in which case you will not be able to move the tokens.